# send email through ajax with php and recaptcha

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm having trouble sending emails using ajax and recaptcha. I'm using 2 different files, my contact form and ajax code is on the index.html and the php code to validade the recaptcha and send the email is the email.php.

This is my ajax code, it is inside the body tag at the bottom of the page

```
<script>
        $(".contact-card").submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var name = $("#name").val();
          var email = $("#email").val();
          var message = $("#message").val();
          var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
          function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
          };

          if (isValidEmail(email)){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
              $('.success').fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
            }
            });
          } else{
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
          }

          return false;
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my php file called email.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $to = "EMAIL";
  $subject = "test";
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $msgBody = 'Name: ' .$name. ' Message: ' .$message;
  $headers = 'From: ' .$email;

  $secretKey = "";
  $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

  $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey";

  $response = file_get_contents($url);

  $response = json_decode($response);

  if($response -> success){
    if( mail($to, $subject, $msgBody, $headers)){
      echo  ("Success");
    } else{
      echo ("failed");
      var_dump($_POST);
    }
  } else{
    echo ("verification failed");
  }
}

?>
```

I'm not using action on my form in the html.

Please help!!!

thank you!!

Comment: There are so many issues that it's not easy to tell how to start :) First, in your php why you check the `submit_form` key, when it's not in the data being send with your ajax? Why are you accessing `g-recaptcha-response` when, again, you're not sending it? (tip: `'g-recaptcha-response' : grecaptcha.getResponse()` ). Why are you making the stringData yourself when the docs say that you can simply give it an object ( https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ) and finally: learn how to troubleshot your code, e.g. in php add var_dump($_POST); to see what you actually have there. Happy coding!

Comment: @konrados i'm not that much of a master at php or ajax...it was working fine before I added the recaptcha, so I stitched a lot of code together from various tutorials I saw online, but I appreciate your comment and I'll be following your recommendations, thank you